# React timer application

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am writing a simple count down timer in React:

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const oneSec = 1000;
  const [secCount, setSecCount] = useState(60);
  const [minCount, setMinCount] = useState(60);
  const [hrCount, setHrCount] = useState(24);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer;    //<= here is my problem.
    if (secCount > 0) {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setSecCount(secCount - 1);
      }, oneSec);
    }
    if (secCount === 0 && minCount > 0) {
      timer = setInterval(() => {
        setSecCount(60);
      }, oneSec);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [secCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer =
      minCount > 0 &&
      setInterval(() => {
        setMinCount(minCount - 1);
      }, 60 * oneSec);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [minCount]);

  return (
    <div>
      {minCount}:{secCount}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am having a hard time with my `useEffect` hooks. The first `useEffect` hook is supposed to update the second field, the logic is simply:

- if `secCount` is bigger than 0, continue to countdown every second
- if `secCount` is zero and `minCount` is bigger than 0, reset `secCount` to 60 and continue to countdown.

But since there are two branches in my first `useEffect` hook, I need to declare the timer variable and reassign it later. Can I get away with declaring it as `let timer`? A const variable does not allow me to change its value.

Comment: Yes, you can. Also, instead of declaring it twice inside useEffect, declare `timer` outside the effect hook and re-assign inside useEffect when needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) vs [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) is fundamentally an ES6+ issue:**

- **const**
  Creates a constant whose scope can be either `global` or `local` to the block in which it is declared. An `initializer` for a constant is required. You must specify its value in the same statement in which it's declared.

```
// wrong
const timer;
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

// right
const timer = 60;
```

- **let**
  Allows you to declare variables that are limited to a scope of a `block` statement, or expression on which it is used, unlike the `var` keyword, which defines a variable globally, or locally to an entire function regardless of block scope. [Please note that a `let` variable is initialized to a value only when a parser evaluates it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone).

```
function do_something() {
  console.log(bar); // undefined
  console.log(foo); // ReferenceError
  var bar = 1;
  let foo = 2;
};
```

**With that said, change the declaration to `let timer;`**

````
// Within the first `useEffect`
useEffect(() => {
     let timer; // change this
     if (secCount > 0) {
       timer = setInterval(() => {setSecCount(secCount - 1)}, oneSec);
     }
     if (secCount === 0 && minCount > 0) {
       timer = setInterval(() => {setSecCount(60)}, oneSec);
     }
     return () => clearInterval(timer);
   }, [secCount]);
```
````